# DNS - Site with subdomains - A NAME, CNAME?

Tags: dns

I am launching the site with many subdomains. Currently when I'm tweaking it on my hosting using hosts file to point to the IP address all if fine. But when I made it live for the whole world, some parts are broken and do not want to load. for example the www and others.

I'm using a third party DNS for DNS. What should I use A NAME records or CNAME records to make it work.

Currently I have 2 records for A records:
localhost
and mydomain IP address

in CNAME I have:
two records for mail and ftp

Answer (score 1):

What type of record you should use depends on what you are referencing to:

- A records are used to reference an IPv4 address. (173.194.70.100)
- CNAME records are used when referencing to another DNS name (google.com)

I don't understand why you want to make a DNS record that points to localhost. Since localhost like 127.0.0.1 always means the local machine anyone trying to connect to that address will connect to their local machine.

Some good examples of the use of common DNS record types: http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/dnsrecords.htm